# Switches and Ifs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've got a slider that changes blur radius:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChangesFinderUp:(id)sender {

_sliderValue = round(self.blurSlider.value);

_effectImage = nil;
_effectImage = [BlurFilter imageByApplyingClearEffectToImage:self.myImage
      withRadius:_sliderValue color:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0]];

self.imageView.image = _effectImage; 
}
```

also I've got a button which should change blur color (the part - [UIColor colorWith..])

```
- (IBAction)setColorGreen:(id)sender {

_effectImage = nil;
_effectImage = [BlurFilter imageByApplyingClearEffectToImage:self.myImage 
withRadius:_sliderValue color:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.15]];

self.imageView.image = _effectImage;
}
```

This button change the color, but when I want to change blur radius the color is resetted , I know that this is because of the code in - `(IBAction)sliderValueChangesFinderUp:(id)sender`.

But how should I create a `switch or if` correctly so when the button green is pressed blur color changes and I may change blur radius without resseting a color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a class level variable for UIColor, for example named colorObject. In your function `- (IBAction)sliderValueChangesFinderUp:(id)sender` access that variable and set it in your line

```
_effectImage = [BlurFilter imageByApplyingClearEffectToImage:self.myImage
      withRadius:_sliderValue color:colorObject];
```

instead of creating a new one from scratch.

In you function `- (IBAction)setColorGreen:(id)sender` , modify that colorObject variable if you need to.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it runs like clockwork!

``_colorObject = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.15];
    _effectImage = [BlurFilter imageByApplyingClearEffectToImage:self.myImage withRadius:_sliderValue color:_colorObject];
    self.imageView.image = _effectImage;``

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking is that you'd like to change the color of the blur passed to `imageByApplyingClearEffectToImage`. A way to do this might be to move the code from the the control actions into a separate message. Both actions would call this message, but you could alter the color. Consider something like the following:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChangesFinderUp:(id)sender
{
    _effectImage = [self blurImage:self.myImage
                         withColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0]];
    self.imageView.image = _effectImage;
}

- (IBAction)setColorGreen:(id)sender
{
    _effectImage = [self blurImage:self.myImage
                         withColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.15]];
    self.imageView.image = _effectImage;
}

- (UIImage *)blurImage:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    return ([BlurFilter imageByApplyingClearEffectToImage:image
                                               withRadius:_sliderValue
                                                    color:color]);
}
```

You're reusing code here by making the color a parameter instead of hardcoding it into a separate function.